# 16.04 with Radeon R7 370 graphics card has slow and stuttering graphics

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon

I recently installed 16.04 64 bit. every window I open or interact with stutters and goes through its animation extremely slowly. Opening the Unity search takes about five seconds, going through roughly one frame per second. I have a quad core processor and a radeon R7 370 graphics card. as far as I can tell the processors are running fine.

I suspect it's an AMD problem, how can I find out for sure? what can I try?

Comment: Start by adding the contents of your `~/.xsession-errors` file at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and provide a link to your question. Do the same for the file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Finally do the same for the output of the command `inxi -SMCGxx` in order to see your system info.